# Summarizing JSON Object Into Another JSON Object

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new at using JSON with JavaScript and am struggling with how to summarize data from one JSON object into another JSON object.

The original JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "general": {
    "version": "v0.4.0",
    "timeStamp": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)",
    "status": "Complete",
    "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
    "outputRollWidth": "2800mm",
    "productionPlan": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
    "workflowConfiguration": {
      "configName": "XX123",
      "press": {
        "name": "XX123"
      }
    }
  },
  "intent": [
    {
      "piId": "62465290",
      "piSequence": "1",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287773301",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P LEFT",
        "leadEdge": "LEFT",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878382_Chardonnay_5up.AotF.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287773301",
      "jobName": "1878382_Chardonnay_5up.AotF",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "174"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465291",
      "piSequence": "2",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287773401",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P LEFT",
        "leadEdge": "LEFT",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878376_CabFranc_5up.AotF.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287773401",
      "jobName": "1878376_CabFranc_5up.AotF",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "174"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465302",
      "piSequence": "3",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287773501",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P LEFT",
        "leadEdge": "LEFT",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878377_Mixed_5up.AotF.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287773501",
      "jobName": "1878377_Mixed_5up.AotF",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "174"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465303",
      "piSequence": "4",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287773601",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P HEAD",
        "leadEdge": "HEAD",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878382_Chardonnay_5up.R.AotF.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287773601",
      "jobName": "1878382_Chardonnay_5up.R.AotF",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "174"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465304",
      "piSequence": "5",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287773701",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P HEAD",
        "leadEdge": "HEAD",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878376_CabFranc_5up.R.AotF.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287773701",
      "jobName": "1878376_CabFranc_5up.R.AotF",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "174"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465305",
      "piSequence": "6",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287773801",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P HEAD",
        "leadEdge": "HEAD",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878377_Mixed_5up.R.AotF.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287773801",
      "jobName": "1878377_Mixed_5up.R.AotF",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "174"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465306",
      "piSequence": "7",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287773901",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P LEFT",
        "leadEdge": "LEFT",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878668_ChocolateChipsDC.5up.AotF_1-174.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287773901",
      "jobName": "1878668_ChocolateChipsDC.5up.AotF_1-174",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "1"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465307",
      "piSequence": "8",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287774001",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P LEFT",
        "leadEdge": "LEFT",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878668_ChocolateChipsDC.5up.AotF_1-174.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287774001",
      "jobName": "1878668_ChocolateChipsDC.5up.AotF_1-174",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "1"
    },
    {
      "piId": "62465308",
      "piSequence": "9",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "4287774101",
      "jobSpec": {
        "name": "600fpm ILO 4C120P LEFT",
        "leadEdge": "LEFT",
        "scaleFactor": "100.6",
        "colorSetup": "inkLimitsOnly_cmyk_120ng_v5_3",
        "qualityMode": "standard",
        "pressProfile": "42inch NORPAC zero gap",
        "paperProfile": "42inch NORPAC"
      },
      "jobPrintFile": "1878668_ChocolateChipsDC.5up.AotF_1-174.pdf",
      "jobProductId": "",
      "jobDesignId": "",
      "jobSourceItemId": "214287774101",
      "jobName": "1878668_ChocolateChipsDC.5up.AotF_1-174",
      "jobPaperName": "",
      "jobPaperWidth": "2800mm",
      "jobLength": "1"
    }
  ],
  "actuals": [
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "diagnostic",
      "jobId": "spit-page-lead-in_0k17p",
      "jobLength": "41 inches"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287773301",
      "jobLength": "772 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "17",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287773301",
      "jobLength": "3360 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "74",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287773501",
      "jobLength": "636 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "14",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287773601",
      "jobLength": "636 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "14",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287773701",
      "jobLength": "3360 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "74",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287773801",
      "jobLength": "772 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "17",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287773901",
      "jobLength": "1012 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "17",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287774001",
      "jobLength": "4404 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "74",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    },
    {
      "outputRollId": "22023_StdJobsAcme",
      "jobType": "Standard",
      "jobId": "PRP4287774101",
      "jobLength": "833 inches",
      "sheetsPrintedGood": "14",
      "sheetsPrintedBad": "0",
      "jobEndPrint": "Wed Feb 02 2022 10:47:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
    }
  ]
}
```

The summary JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "rollId": "D34100001",
  "rollWidth": 33,
  "totalLength": 3750,
  "totalQuantity": "120500",
  "detail": [
    {
      "jobId": "PRP4287773301",
      "jobName": "1878382_Chardonnay_5up.AotF",
      "jobLength": 1000
    },
    {
      "jobId": "PRP4287773501",
      "jobName": "Acme / CZ372L21",
      "jobLength": 636
    },
    {
      "jobId": "PRP4287773601",
      "jobName": "Alani / SPTC00010",
      "jobLength": 636
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to process rollId, rollWidth, totalLength, and totalQuantity easy enough, but I'm struggling how to handle the detail array summarization. The array should be comprised of intent.jobId and intent.jobName and the total of actuals.jobLength for each jobId.

My code currently:

```
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const RollResults = require('../models/rollResultsModel');

// Process roll results
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const rawRollResults = req.body;
    const finalRollResults = {};
    var totalQty = 0;
    var totalLength = 0;
    try {
        finalRollResults.rollId = rawRollResults.general.outputRollId;
        finalRollResults.rollWidth = Math.round(Number(rawRollResults.general.outputRollWidth.slice(0, -2)) / 25.4);
        for (var i = 0; i < rawRollResults.actuals.length; i++)
        {
            if (rawRollResults.actuals[i].jobType === "Standard")
            {
                totalLength += Number(rawRollResults.actuals[i].jobLength.slice(0, -7));
                totalQty += Number(rawRollResults.actuals[i].sheetsPrintedGood);
            }
        }
        finalRollResults.totalLength = Math.round(totalLength / 12);
        finalRollResults.totalQuantity = totalQty;
        res.json(finalRollResults);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});



module.exports = router;
```

I would assume that I need to accomplish this in two passes through the original JSON, the first pass adding detail.jobId and detail.jobName for each original JSON intent, and then cycle through the original JSON actuals and update each new JSON detail accordingly, but I am unaware of how to accomplish this.

Comment: 1) Validate your Json: Copy/paste your "Summary JSON" example into an on-line Json Validation tool, e.g. https://jsonlint.com. 2) I don't see where you're iterating through the "intents[]" array in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you have a function that is trying to do way too much. To many different things. Refactor it into smaller functions that each do one simple thing. It makes it easier to test, and easier to debug.

But at its heart, the problem doesn't seem like it ought to be anything more complicated than a simple mapper.

You first need a way to convert to inches, something like this:

```
function convertToInches( measurement ) {
    const [ n = 0, units = 'mm' ] = /^(\d+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$/.exec(measurement) ?? [];
    let f;
    switch (units) {
        case 'mm'     : f = 25.4      ; break ;
        case 'cm'     : f = 2.54      ; break ;
        case 'in'     : f = 1.0       ; break ;
        case 'ins'    : f = 1.0       ; break ;
        case 'inches' : f = 1.0       ; break;
        default       : f = undefined ; break ;
    }
    return f ? Math.round( n / f ) : undefined ;
}
```

And you need a way to correlate the `intents` and the `actuals` by `jobId`, something like this:

```
function getJobs( results ) {
  const jobsById = {};
  
  for ( const intent of results.intent ) {
    if (intent.jobType !== 'Standard' ) continue;
    
    jobsById[intent.jobId] = { intent };
    
  }
  
  for ( const actual of results.actual ) {
    if (actual.jobType !== 'Standard' ) continue;
    
    jobsById[actual.jobId] = jobsById[actual.jobId] ?? {};
    jobsById[actual.jobId].actual = actual;
    
  }
  
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------
  // now that we have an 'intent' and an 'actual' matched by job ID,
  // it's easy to create the job detail that we'll need.
  //
  // Note that 'qty' will get discarded when we no longer need it
  //
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------
  const jobs = Object.values( jobsById ).map( job => ({
    ...job,
    detail: {
      jobId     : job.actual.jobId,
      jobName   : job.intent.jobName,
      jobLength : ConvertToInches( job.actual.jobLength ),
      qty       : Number( job.actual.sheetsPrintedGood )
    }
  }) );

  return jobs;
}
```

And once you have that, it's just a simple mapper to product what you want:

```
function mapRollResults( results ) {
    const jobs = getJobs( results );
    return {
        rollId        : results.general.outputRollId,
        rollWidth     : convertToInches( results.general.outputRollWidth ),
        totalLength   : jobs.reduce( (sum,j) => sum += j.detail.jobLength , 0 ),
        totalQuantity : jobs.reduce( (sum,j) => sum += j.detail.qty       , 0 ),
        details       : jobs.map( j => j.detail )
                            .map( d => {
                                delete d.qty;
                                return d;
                            }),
    };
}
```